# List of standard locality/ sub-locality for Singapore Google Maps API v3?

Tags: geocoding

Is there a place where I can view the list of standard locality/ sub-locality of Singapore?

I'm working on a web app that tag places to small regions in Singapore e.g. Downtown, Sentosa island. Singapore is a small country but it's a big city. This was already done by another developer whom I cannot contact now (perhaps the small regions were created manually and it's not possible at all using Google Maps API?)

I borrow some code from [here](http://ubilabs.github.com/geocomplete/) but no sub-locality is shown so I wonder what's wrong. Perhaps, there is no sub-locality at all for Singapore, under Google Maps' view.

Comment: This question is not about the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)

Comment: what is it about then @Marcelo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**Geonames**](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/) geographical database is available for download free of charge under a creative commons attribution license. The **SN.zip** file has the data for Singapore.

Comment: I didn't know that Google Maps use such database instead of having its own, thanks, David

Comment: Google has its own database but it limits its use.

Comment: The SG.zip file and not SN.zip file has the data for Singapore.